# chose language navbar-like

Tags: html, css

I'm starting to get desperate cause I just cannot figure this out, so I'd like to ask you guys for help.

HTML:

```
<div id="wp-nav">
    <ul>
       <li><a href='#'>ENGLISH</a>
          <ul>
             <li><img src="images/gb.gif"/>
             </li>
          </ul>
       </li>
        <li><a href='#'>SRPSKI</a>
          <ul>
             <li><img src="images/rs.gif"/>
             </li>
          </ul>
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wp-nav {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 130px;
    width: auto;
}
#wp-nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
#wp-nav > ul > li {
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
}
#wp-nav > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
#wp-nav > ul > li:hover {
  background: #fff;
}
#wp-nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Verdana, "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 50px;
    -webkit-transition: color .15s;
    -moz-transition: color .15s;
    -o-transition: color .15s;
    transition: color .15s;
}
#wp-nav > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #000;
}
#wp-nav > ul > li > ul {
    margin: 10px auto 0;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    text-align: center;
    width: 45px;
    height: 30px;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s .1s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s .1s;
    -o-transition: all .3s .1s;
    transition: all .3s .1s;

}
#wp-nav > ul > li:hover > ul{
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

So, basically, when I hover over English I want the Britain flag to show underneath the tab but I don't want to keep any properties of English `<li>` and when I :hover that flag, I don't want the English `<li>` to remain white as if it's hovered. Same goes for Serbian.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you want to create the problem? [Flags should not be used as symbols of languages](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/flags.html).

Comment: so when hover over the flag you like to display the English button in default style ?

Comment: About that, I'm sorry, I saw that on so many websites, flags being used as symbols for languages. Thanks for the info though.
@SonasishRoy Exactly! And the problem is solved, thanks for replaying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `#wp-nav > ul > li:hover` to `#wp-nav > ul > li > a:hover`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HmhAd/1/)

Comment: Thank you! I was really getting desperate and the solution was this simple. Ah :/ Thanks a lot!

Comment: I clicked it now, I'm new to this website so I wasn't sure how to thank you in a way that can benefit you. :)

Comment: that's why I respond to comments left on my answers. The site's meant to help. Regardless, accepting an answer helps others, as if they have the same issue they'll need to see which answer was the one that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Add this.
Css:

```
#wp-nav > ul> li:hover > a {
    color: #fff;  
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LTpRC/

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Though my problem is solved with the answer above. :)